# Sum dataframe column by conditional row criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I summarizes a column based on a dynamic value in the existing row? Using the example below, I'd like to iterate over each row (`x`), calculate the sum of all `Clicks` where `Date == x.Date_Yesterday`, and add the total as a new column.

**Input data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2021-09-14','2021-09-14','2021-09-14','2021-09-13','2021-09-12','2021-09-12','2021-09-11'],
    'Date_Yesterday': ['2021-09-13','2021-09-13','2021-09-13','2021-09-12','2021-09-11','2021-09-11','2021-09-10'],
    'Clicks': [100,100,100,50,10,10,1]
})


   Date           Date_Yesterday  Clicks
0  2021-09-14     2021-09-13      100
1  2021-09-14     2021-09-13      100
2  2021-09-14     2021-09-13      100
3  2021-09-13     2021-09-12      50
4  2021-09-12     2021-09-11      10
5  2021-09-12     2021-09-11      10
6  2021-09-11     2021-09-10      1
```

**Desired Output data:**

```
Date          Date_Yesterday   Clicks  Total_Clicks_Yesterday
2021-09-14    2021-09-13       100     50
2021-09-14    2021-09-13       100     50
2021-09-14    2021-09-13       100     50
2021-09-13    2021-09-12       50      20
2021-09-12    2021-09-11       10      1
2021-09-12    2021-09-11       10      1
2021-09-11    2021-09-10       1       N/A
```

Calculating the `Total_Clicks_Yesterday` is simple with a static value:

```
clicks_yesterday = df['Total_Clicks_Yesterday'] = df.loc[df['Date'] == '2021-09-13', 'Clicks'].sum()
print(clicks_yesterday)

         Date Date_Yesterday  Clicks  Total_Clicks_Yesterday
0  2021-09-14     2021-09-13     100                      50
1  2021-09-14     2021-09-13     100                      50
2  2021-09-14     2021-09-13     100                      50
3  2021-09-13     2021-09-12      50                      50
4  2021-09-12     2021-09-11      10                      50
5  2021-09-12     2021-09-11      10                      50
6  2021-09-11     2021-09-10       1                      50
```

but I'm not sure how to make it dynamic for each line item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can `groupby` the column Date and `sum` the Clicks to get the number of clicks each day. Then use `map` on the column Date_yesterday with the result of the `groupby` operation to align the number of clicks with the previous day

```
df['Total_Clicks_Yesterday'] = df['Date_Yesterday'].map(df.groupby('Date')['Clicks'].sum())
print(df)
         Date Date_Yesterday  Clicks  Total_Clicks_Yesterday
0  2021-09-14     2021-09-13     100                    50.0
1  2021-09-14     2021-09-13     100                    50.0
2  2021-09-14     2021-09-13     100                    50.0
3  2021-09-13     2021-09-12      50                    20.0
4  2021-09-12     2021-09-11      10                     1.0
5  2021-09-12     2021-09-11      10                     1.0
6  2021-09-11     2021-09-10       1                     NaN
```

Comment: This works great -- I used a very simplified example with only 1 dimension (`Date_Yesterday`) to group by. How would this be extended to handle multiple dimensions in the groupby? For example, if there was another column `Page Name` and I want to group by `Date_Yesterday` and `Page Name`.

Comment: @DavidBeaudway you can use several columns in the `groupby(['Date_Yesterday','Page_Name'])...`, but then you cant't use `map` because it workds only on a Series (1 column) and not several. you will need to use `merge`, more like the other answer here

Answer (score 2):

in one line:

```py
pd.merge(df, df.groupby('Date')['Clicks'].sum().rename('Total_Clicks_Yesterday'), how='left', left_on='Date_Yesterday', right_index=True)
```

Here I'm [merging](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) two dataframes: the original dataframe, and a second one which is the groupby (documentation).

The `groupby` is grouping over the current date, and summing it up:

```py
df.groupby('Date')['Clicks'].sum().rename('Total_Clicks_Yesterday')
Out[16]: 
Date
2021-09-11      1
2021-09-12     20
2021-09-13     50
2021-09-14    300
Name: Total_Clicks_Yesterday, dtype: int64
```

It's the easiest way to get a series as you desired, grouping and summing over a value. Although the name of the index is "date", I'm going to merge it as if it is the date of yesterday.

Now all we need to get this small series together with the original dataframe. I recommend taking a look at [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) to understand it better.
Basically, I'm merging based on the left dataframe (`df`), where I'm comparing the 'Date_Yesterday' column of `df` with the index of the `groupby df` (which to I refer to as "data of yesterday")

The result:

```py
pd.merge(df, df.groupby('Date')['Clicks'].sum().rename('Total_Clicks_Yesterday'), how='left', left_on='Date_Yesterday', right_index=True)
Out[17]: 
         Date Date_Yesterday  Clicks  Total_Clicks_Yesterday
0  2021-09-14     2021-09-13     100                    50.0
1  2021-09-14     2021-09-13     100                    50.0
2  2021-09-14     2021-09-13     100                    50.0
3  2021-09-13     2021-09-12      50                    20.0
4  2021-09-12     2021-09-11      10                     1.0
5  2021-09-12     2021-09-11      10                     1.0
6  2021-09-11     2021-09-10       1                     NaN
```